# Storing local files in Docker Volume for sharing

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm new to Docker, so this may be an obvious question that I'm just not using the right search terms to find an answer to, so my apologies if that is the case.

I'm trying to stand up a new CI/CD Pipeline using a purpose built container.  So far, I've been using someone else's container, but I need more control over the available dependencies, so I need my own container.  To that end, I've built a container (Ubuntu), and I have a local (host) directory for the dependencies, and another for the project I'm building.  Both are connected to the container using Docker Volumes (-v option), like this.

```
docker run --name buildbox \
-v /projectpath:/home/project/ \
-v /dependencies:/home/libs \
buildImage buildScript.sh
```

Since this is going to eventually live in a Docker repo and be accessed by a GitLab CI/CD Pipeline, I want to store the dependencies directory in as small of a container as possible that I can push up to the Docker repo alongside my Ubuntu build container.  That way I can have the Pipeline pull both containers, map the dependencies container to the build container (--volumes-from), and map the project to be built using the -v option; e.g.:

```
docker run --name buildbox \
-v /projectpath:/home/project/ \
--volumes-from depend_vol \
buildImage buildScript.sh
```

Thus, I pull buildImage and depend_vol from the Docker repo, run buildImage while attaching the dependencies container and project directory as volumes, then run the build script (and extract the build artifact when it's done).  The reason I want them separate is in case I want to create different build containers that use common libraries, or if I want to create version specific dependency containers without having a full OS stored (I have plans for this).

Now, I could just start a lightweight generic container (like busybox) and copy everything into it, but I was wondering if there was simply a way to attach the volume and then store the contents in the image when the container shuts down.  Everything [I've seen about making a portable data store / volume](https://dzone.com/articles/docker-backup-your-data-volumes-to-docker-hub) starts with all the data already copied into the container.

But I want to take my local host dependencies directory and store it in a container.  Is there a straightforward way to do this?  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

So this works, if not what I was hoping for, since I'm still doing a lot of file copy (just with tarballs).

```
# Create a tarball of the files on the host to store, don't store the full path
tar -cvf /home/projectFiles.tar -C /home/projectFiles/ .

# Start a lightweight docker container (busybox) with a volume connection to the host (/home:/backup), then extract the tarball into the container
# cd to the drive root and untar the tarball
docker run --name libraryVolume \
  -v /home:/backup \
  busybox \
  /bin/sh -c \
  "cd / && mkdir /projectLibs && tar -xvf /backup/projectFiles.tar -C /projectLibs"

# Don't forget to commit the container image
docker commit libraryVolume
```

That's it.  Then push to the repo.

To use it, pull the repo, then start the data volume:

```
docker run --name projLib \
  -v /projectLibs \
  --entrypoint "/bin/sh" \
  libraryVolume
```

Then start the container (**projBuild**) that is going to reference the data volume (**projLib**).

```
docker run --it --name projBuild \
  --volumes-from=projLib \
  -v /home/mySourceCode:/buildProject \
  --entrypoint /buildProject/buildScript.sh \
  builderImage
```

Seems to work.